# How to convert multiple .img images to .bmp format?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, bmp

I am trying to use Python to read MULTIPLE images from a folder that are currently in .img format and convert them all to .bmp format.

I've successfully done it with just one image however I am very new to Python and have trouble reading multiple images and converting them.

Here was my attempt at 1 image:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import sys

img = "hand1.img"
imgOut = "hand2bmp.bmp"
image = Image.open(img).convert('RGB').convert('L').save(imgOut)
```

Here was my attempt at multiple images:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import sys, glob, os

folder = 'C:/Users/Josep/Documents/code/test_file/BMLs/BMLs_Original'

for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder,'*.bmp')):
    Image.open(filename).convert('RGB').convert('L').save(filename)
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-4] + '.bmp').save(filename)
```

I expected to convert the files to .bmp format, however, when I run the code I see no change in the images.

Comment: Why would you want files in ancient, old-fashioned Microsoft BMP format? Surely PNG is preferable?

Comment: The person I am volunteering for asked for the images in BMP format. If it were up to me, I would agree with you on that.

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligenceDev You should not add [SOLVED] to the title of your question, in SO you only need to mark one of the answers as correct

Comment: My apologies. I did both, figuring it would save people time when scrolling through potential solutions to problems. I will make sure I do not do this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You more-or-less just need to do what you did for one file to each file in the folder.

```
import glob, os, sys
from PIL import Image

folder = 'C:/Users/Josep/Documents/code/test_file/BMLs/BMLs_Original'

for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder, '*.img')):
    image = Image.open(filepath).convert('RGB').convert('L')
    new_filepath = os.path.splitext(filepath)[0] + '.bmp'
    image.save(new_filepath)
```

Note that this creates *new* image files, leaving the originals intact — in other words it doesn't rename the originals. If you want to get rid of the originals, you could delete them with `os.remove()` after saving the converted image in the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it and can confirm, that is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: ArtificialIntelligenceDev: Thanks. I noticed I used the wrong variable on the last line and have fixed my answer — but it sounds like you figured that out…

Comment: Correct. Thank you again.